# What is this Icon on the Right side

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut, hotkeys

I activated a Shortcut and now my line is splitting. How can I redo it? (Control + Z does nothing.)
I tried to search on the internet too but didn't find anything useful.

[image: ImageZoomed]

[image: ImageFull]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-manage-word-wrap-in-the-editor?view=vs-2019

Comment: Your line is not splitting, it's wrapping. Most likely you caught a shortcut which enabled line wrapping. You can disable it via Edit->Advanced->Word Wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [word wrap option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-manage-word-wrap-in-the-editor?view=vs-2019)

> You can set and clear the Word wrap option. When this option is set,
> the portion of a long line that extends beyond the current width of
> the Code Editor window is displayed on the next line. When this option
> is cleared, for example, to facilitate the use of line numbering, you
> can scroll to the right to see the ends of long lines.

You can disable it by

1. <kbd>Tools menu</kbd>  <kbd>Options</kbd>.
2. <kbd>All Languages</kbd>  <kbd>General options</kbd>
3. Under Settings, select or clear the Word wrap option.